# PaperTrail retrieve has_many association

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, paper-trail-gem

I am using `PaperTrail` to version models. For a single model this works pretty well. However I cannot manage to restore a simple has_many relation, although the docs state that this should work.

I have two simple models:

```
class Template < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :assets, dependent: :destroy
  has_paper_trail
  #also has a title
end

class Asset < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :template
  has_paper_trail
  has_attached_file :file, :path => ':class/:id/:filename.:extension'
  do_not_validate_attachment_file_type :file
end
```

This is the procedure I use to test the versioning.

```rb
template = Template.create

template.title = 'initial'
template.assets.create()
template.save

title1 = template.title  #initial
count1 = template.assets.count #1

template.title = 'v2'
template.assets.create()
template.save

title2 = template.title #v2
count2 = template.assets.count #2

template_old = template.versions.last.reify(:has_many => true)

title3 = template_old.title #initial
count3 = template_old.assets.count #2, should be 1

template.title = 'v3'
template.assets.last.destroy()
template.save

title4 = template.title #v3
count4 = template.assets.count #1

template_old = template.versions.last.reify(:has_many => true)

title5 = template_old.title #v2
count5 = template_old.assets.count #1, should be 2
```

I have tracked this to the version_concern.rb reify_has_many_directly method. But to me it seems like it is always just restoring the relations from the current live version.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

When you call `template_old.assets.count` you cause a database query against the live database. Instead, use `template_old.assets.length`.